# How to set PathNameAlias SharedFiles in DNN7

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I get this error message:

NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://dnndev.me/Resources/Shared/Scripts/jquery.min.js?cdv=49"

when loading my webpage.

I think this is related to the include:

```
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" PathNameAlias="SharedScripts" FilePath="jquery.min.js" />
```

and the fact that "jquery.min.js" is in a sub folder of what I believe "SharedScripts" to be.
However i have not succeeded in finding where SharedScripts is set.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a relative path? Eg

```
<dnn:DnnJsInclude ID="DnnJsIncludeJquery" FilePath="~/Resources/Shared/SharedScripts/jquery.min.js" runat="server" />
```

The '~/' will take the path from the web root (so the path the jquery will be  http://dnndev.me/Resources/Shared/SharedScripts/jquery.min.js)

Alternatively, you can navigate to Host -> Advanced Settings, and then select jQuery settings from advance settings. This will show the jquery version (and jQueryUI version) DNN will automatically add to the page. You can change the jquery version used by DNN for your site.
You shouldn't need to add your own jquery unless you wish to use a different version than the one DNN is adding. DNN also only adds the minified version unless you tick the use debug version checkbox.